# How do I call a function that has self.write from another class with no inheritance?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was trying to use AppEngine to get the following code to work:

```
 class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def show(self, display=""):
        msg = """<!doctype html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                <title> Message </title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <div name=text>
                                     %(text)s
                                </div>
                            </body>
                        </html>"""
                self.response.write(msg % {"text":display})

    class RetCall(webapp2.RequestHandler):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
            text_entered = self.request.get('text')
            text_entered = "Hey " + text_entered
            m = MainPage()
            m.show(text_entered)
```

There's a get function within `MainPage`  which I've excluded.
When I run it this way, I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

I thought by using `m` - an instance of `MainPage` as the object, it should work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I've also tried MainPage.show(self, text_entered) which gives me the error : "unbound method show() must be called with MainPage instance as first argument" and MainPage.show(m, text_entered) which gives me the error : "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'". I've looked over the web for these options. P.S: I'm not using inheritance between classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass self.response

```
 def show(response, display=""):
        msg = """<!doctype html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                <title> Message </title>
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <div name=text>
                                     %(text)s
                                </div>
                            </body>
                        </html>"""
        response.write(msg % {"text":display})

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    pass

class RetCall(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        text_entered = self.request.get('text')
        text_entered = "Hey " + text_entered
        show(self.response, text_entered)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `webapp2.RequestHandler` didn't get a `response` when it was constructed. Webapp2 automatically creates a response class and passses it to your handler when a request is routed to it. See webapp2's documentation on [routing](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/app.html#router) for more info.

If you simply want to test out your handler, have a look at webapp2's [unit testing](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/testing.html#guide-testing) docs. It's not only useful for unit testing, but also for just trying things out in an interactive environment like the python shell.